# jquery "this" to separate hovers

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup, jquery-hover

i have a custom player that my client is using, and they javascript they gave me is bad... real bad. I really don't want to have to redo it from scratch so I thought I could take their origional code

```
var togglePlayer = function(){
        $('.jp-gui').slideUp();
        $('#jp_container, #jp_container2').hover(
            function () {
                $('.jp-gui').slideDown();
            },
            function () {
                $('.jp-gui').slideUp();
            }
        );
    };
```

I tried fixing it with this:

```
var togglePlayer = function(){
        $('.jp-gui').slideUp();
        $('#jp_container, #jp_container2').hover(
            function () {
                $(this + '.jp-gui').slideDown();
            },
            function () {
                $(this + '.jp-gui').slideUp();
            }
        );
    };
```

Now it seams to just not accept the hover. I rewrote it completely with a .toggleSlide, that fixed the hover problem but made 10 more problems.

Does anyone know an easy fix so that when I hover over #jp_container it doesn't do the hover animation on the #jp_container2 and vice versa?

Comment: `this` in the callback is a DOM element. Concatenating it with string won't do any good. Try `$('.jp-gui', this)`

Comment: BAMF! You win. You should have answered this so I could up vote it.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#jp_container, #jp_container2').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.jp-gui').stop(true, true).slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        function () {
            $(this + '.jp-gui').slideDown();
        },
```

`this`, in the context of a jQuery event handler, is the DOM element to which the handler was attached (or delegated, in case of event delegation). Converting it to string will do no good.

Try:

```
        function () {
            $('.jp-gui', this).slideDown();
        },
```

(then the second argument is called the context) or

```
        function () {
            $(this).find('.jp-gui').slideDown();
        },
```

instead. Both will select all `.jp-gui` elements within the event target (`#jp_container` or `#jp_container2`).

---

If you want to make further changes, note

`#jp_container, #jp_container2` can sometimes be replaced with `[id^="jp_container"]` (select all elements whose ID starts with the specified string). Adding a common class to both containers would be even better.

Also, as noted by @Michael, a pair of `slideUp`/`slideDown` can be replaced by a single `slideToggle`. This may not always be the best solution but it does shorten the code.

@Michael also suggests stopping the previous animation with `stop(true, true)`. If you don't stop the animation, the next one will be delayed after the current animation(s enqueued), which may cause the element to slide up and down repeatedly after multiple hover events have been generated. If the container changes its size or its child escapes its container, without `stop`, might be even possible to get an infinite loop if each animation triggers an extra hover event.